# Jquery : using show() for current item on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show  edit link on mouseenter  event and then hide  it on mouseleave , this is my html structure

```
<div class="row interests">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <img src="images/int/1.jpg">
    <p>Sports</p>
    <a href="#"> <span class="fa fa-edit"> </span></a>
</div>
```

this is my  css for edit link

```
.interests .fa-edit {
    display: none;
}
```

jquery for mouseenter and mouseleave events

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.interests').mouseenter(function(){
         $(this).find('.fa-edit').show();
     }).mouseleave(function(){
         $(this).find('.fa-edit').hide();
     });
 });
```

now problem is that above html structure is repeating 10 times and what I want is to show edit link for current item that is being  hovered  , while one now it shows all the  edit links in all grids when I hover one of these , How do I fix this please help.

Comment: item means out of 10 interests i  hover over 1 (interestes class) and need to show  edit link inside this interests class

Comment: Are you saying the outer ".interests" div repeats 10 times? It's unclear because your snippet has an inner div opening tag on line 2 but there's only one closing `</div>` tag. If the outer ".interests" does repeat your JS should work. (Though either way this can be done with just CSS styles, no need for JS.)

Comment: This is already the case (if you close outer div...). So provide MCVE replicating your issue   https://jsfiddle.net/2f23Lzqv/

Comment: okay i changed my selector like this  :  $('.interests .col-md-3').mouseenter(function(){
                   $(this).find('.fa-edit').show();  that worked

Comment: @Sikander And why don't you use valid HTML markup instead?!  Meaning closing all relevant DIVs. And what about using CSS only?

Comment: i did not post all  html code that was only to show how its structured , and how  js is related . to it  i could not  use css for current hovered item only  thats why i wanted to use $(this)  .

Comment: You can use CSS for current hovered item. Two answers (one now deleted) showed you how - it just didn't quite work because you didn't make your html structure clear. If you fixed the selector the same way you fixed it in your JS it would work.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
           $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.interests').mouseenter(function(){
                    $(this).find('a span.fa-edit').parent().show();
                }).mouseleave(function(){
                    $(this).find('a span.fa-edit').parent().hide();
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row interests">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <img src="images/int/1.jpg">
    <p>Sports</p>
    <a href="#">xxxxx <span class="fa fa-edit"> </span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **not** with *javacript / jQuery* code but the html is not correct. The second div (`<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">`) does not have closing tag

**[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eu40psjs/10/)**

```
<div class="row interests">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <img src="images/int/1.jpg">
    <p>Sports</p>
    <a href="#"> <span class="fa fa-edit">1 </span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Its better to do it using `:hover` css without jQuery / Javascript

**[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eu40psjs/11/)**

```
.interests:hover .fa-edit {
    display: block;
}
```